# React-Native image viewer with zoom and swiper

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I have an array of images in a Swiper, where I can swipe through them, and when I click in on of them it open on a Modal (using Lightbox). But Lightbox doesn't have Pinch-to-Zoom or swiping.

So im looking for a solution to this. I already have a swiper, but when I open an image, I want to still be able to swipe through all the images (just like Facebook, you can view all the photos, or open one and swipe through them). In addition to this I need to be able to Pinch-to-Zoom.

Right now this is my code:

(Relevant code)

```
      <Swiper
        styles={{flex: 1}}
        height={250}
        renderPagination={this.renderPagination}
        paginationStyle={{
          bottom: -23, left: null, right: 10
        }} loop={false}>
          {this.state.imagens.map((item, index) => {
            return(
              <NetworkImage
                source={{uri: `URL/${item.Ficheiro}`, height:250, width: Dimensions.get('window').width}}>
                <Lightbox navigator={this.props.navigator}>
                  <Image
                    style={{ height: 300 }}
                    source={{ uri: `URL/${item.Ficheiro}` }}
                  />
                </Lightbox>
              </NetworkImage>
            );
          })}
      </Swiper>
```

Im using this library for the swiper https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper and I saw it has a PhotoView, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to get it to work? would you please share the code on github? I am new to react-native thus I cannot comprehend from the answer... thanks a lot..

Comment: Hi! I ended up giving up the way I was trying to do and I've done something different, and the images does not zoom. I ended up using the swiper to view the images, and once I click one of them it opens that image in another screen, in a carousel (https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel), which I can swipe through all of them too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've been trying to implement something similar to this as well.

I'm using `react-native-image-zoom-viewer` for the zoomed in mode after clicking one of the pictures in the swiper. Within the modal, you can zoom in and out an image while swiping between images.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-zoom-viewer

I haven't fully implemented the solution yet but it seems you can just wrap the ImageViewer component in any Modal that you can open/close it programmatically.

```
<Modal visible={this.state.isModalOpened} transparent={true}>
   <ImageViewer imageUrls={images} index={this.state.currentImageIndex}/>
</Modal>
```

And with the modal somewhere sitting in your page, for the Swiper you can map over your images and return clickable images as follows:

```
<View style={styles.slide} key={index}>
   <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {this.openModal(index)}}>
     <Image
       resizeMode="cover"
       style={styles.image}
       source={{ uri: img.url }}
     />
   </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
</View>
```

As seen above, each image is wrapped by an onPress that opens the modal according to the image index, so it opens the ImageViewer Modal on the right photo.

And openModal should look something like this:

```
function openModal(index) {
   this.setState({isModalOpened: true, currentImageIndex: index })
}
```

And the state should be:

```
this.state={
  isModalOpened: false,  //Controls if modal is opened or closed
  currentImageIndex: 0   //Controls initial photo to show for modal
}
```

Comment: I tried that, and when I click the image in the swiper, it simply does nothing.. Do you have any code you can share?

Comment: It won't work for images fetched from an API... It works just fine with other images, like the example on their GitHub. This is not working:  `<ImageViewer imageUrls={{ uri: 'URL/${item.Ficheiro}' }} index={this.state.currentImageIndex}/>`

Comment: According to their documentation it should be an array of objects with url as a must have attribute. So it's `<ImageViewer imageUrls={[{url: "lala"},{url: "lala"},{url: "lala"}]}` />

Comment: I can't have an array like that, as I don't know how many photos it comes from the API. Thats why I need to use `URL/${item.Ficheiro}`. Thats how it works with the swiper. Swiper runs the URL multiple times, as long that is data on `item.Ficheiro`, and shows all the images.

Comment: Yes but you'll need to find a way to map that data into an array of url objects then. For example declare a constant within render function: `const imageUrls = this.state.imagens.map((item,index)=>{ return {url: item.url}}` and then `<ImageViewer imageUrls={imageUrls} />`

Comment: Of course! That was stupid by me ahah it worked thanks! Just a quick question, how do I close the modal? or do I need to make a function for that? btw, ill accept your answer!

Comment: No problem haha, to close the modal you'll need to programmatically make isModalVisible to false, so you can have a cancel button somewhere which triggers a function that sets isModalVisible to be false.

Comment: @RajeshNasit you can add close button in the Modal and on tapaping it make a setState call to make isModalVisible to false. Or you can enable swipeDownToClose method according to their documentation. Hope any of the above point helps!

Comment: Facing rendering issue on latest iOS but good in android. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **react-native-image-zoom-viewer** with hooks
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-zoom-viewer

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ImageViewer from 'react-native-image-zoom-viewer';

const MultipleImageFeaturePost = ({ route, navigation }) => {
            
     **const { item } = route.params
    const [showModal, setshowModal] = useState(false)
    const [imageIndex, setimageIndex] = useState(0)
    const images = item.post_medias.map(s => ({ url: s.media_name })) **
            
     const renderImages = (item, index) => (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
     ** setimageIndex(index)
        setshowModal(true) **
     }}>
            <Image
                source={{ uri: item.media_name }}
                resizeMode='stretch'
                style={{ alignSelf: 'center', height: hp('35'), marginVertical: hp('1%'), width: wp('86%'), borderRadius: 7, backgroundColor: '#A9A9A9' }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#E5EBEE' }}>
            <FlatList
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                data={item.post_medias}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) => renderImages(item, index)}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.post_media_id + ''}
            />
         
        ** <Modal
            visible={showModal}
            transparent={true}
            onSwipeDown={() => setshowModal(false)}>
            <ImageViewer
                imageUrls={images}
                index={imageIndex}
                onSwipeDown={() => setshowModal(false)}
                // onMove={data => console.log(data)}
                enableSwipeDown={true}/>
        </Modal> **
     </SafeAreaView >
     )
     }

export default MultipleImageFeaturePost
```